# getting error in calling a service while running angular2 unit tests with jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I'm working on testing an angular service, I've written code in typescript but when I run my test cases, I get error for "this.someFunction.show()" is not a function, and "this.someFunction.show()" is in my actual service.
Here is what I'm trying to do.

**myService.spec.ts**

```
import { dep1, dep......m dep-n } from '../../../../some-modules';
describe('ServiceTest', () => {
let cashPaymentHandlerService : CashPaymentHandlerService;
it('for cash, when pick list enabled, 1 cash drawer, adds payment line', () => {
  methodOne(); //work fine
  methodTwo(false); //work fine
  methodThree(true); //work fine      
  methodFour(); //work fine
  methodFive(1); //work fine
  methodSix(); //work fine
  givenDependanciesAreMocked();
  whenHandlePaymentIsInvoked();
  expect(cashDrawerService.openCashDrawer).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

function givenDependanciesAreMocked(){
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 providers: [
   {provide: ServiceOne, useValue: serviceOne},
   {provide: ServiceTwo, useValue: serviceTwo},
   {provide: ServiceN, useValue: serviceN},
   CashPaymentHandlerService
 ]
});
cashPaymentHandlerService = TestBed.get(CashPaymentHandlerService);
}

function whenHandlePaymentIsInvoked() : any {
  cashPaymentHandlerService.handlePayment(cashPaymentRequest);
}
```

Here is my **cash-payment-handler.service.ts** file

```
import { dep1, dep......m dep-n } from '../../../../some-modules';

export class CashPaymentHandlerService {
constructor(private service1 : Service1,
          private service2: Service2,
          private serviceN: ServiceN){
}

handlePayment(cashPaymentRequest: CashPaymentRequest) {
  let request = new service1();
  request.initialAmount = this.service2.dataModel.transactionDataModel.balance();
  request.onValueEntered = (response: AmountPromptResponse) => {
    if (!response.cancelled){
      this.addCashPaymentLine(response.value, cashPaymentRequest); // runs fine
    }
  };
  this.serviceN.show(request); //getting error on this line
}
```

}

and code from **ServiceN.ts** is

```
constructor(
private someController: SomeController){
}

show(options?: NewRequest): void {
if (!options){
  options = new NewRequest();
}

this.someController.show(PromptComponent, options); // PromptComponent imported from some other component
}
```

I've searched for solutions on many forums and spent a whole day on it but couldn't get is resolved. Any help would be highly appreciated. Meherbani hosi nay.

Comment: If the error is in the service then is not on the .spec, then is not a Testing error but a Service error, right? Or maybe I didn't understand well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolved** this, I had to add mocking functions for the "**this.serviceN.show(request);**" in my "**myService.spec.ts**" file and it worked fine, as my service which I was trying to test was calling some further components and when unit test was calling it, it was unable to find proper references to that further methods in different services so it was failing. Mocking those dependencies solved the issue for me.